# Android Warning: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain

Tags: android, android-spinner

I need your eyes, guys. I've strive with my code for a long time, and I still stay stuck like an old rack.

You see, there're numerous topics related to android warning:

```
W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub...
```

I've read a lot of them, did not found anything helpful and my eyes are tired.

I'm working on a spinner component, which first item, named as *Add new...* fires a Dialog to add another item to the list. Because I have currently two such spinners (in one activity), I created a wrapper class for the spinners, which takes care of the logic and I've created class, which extends `DialogFragment` since both spinners fires similar dialog with `<EditText>`, just different titles.

But on the view, only the first spinner works. The second spinner, when choosig option to *Add new...*, does nothing, just produce warning written above.

## Spinner wrapper

Is inner class of `KegAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity` and looks like this:

```
public class ExtendableSpinner implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    private static final int ADD_NEW_ID = -1;

    private final Spinner _mSpinner;
    private final String _mTableName;
    private final int _mAddNewTitle;
    private final MatrixCursor _mAddOptionsCursor;

    private Uri _mAdapterUri;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter _mAdapter;
    private boolean _mWasTouched;

    public ExtendableSpinner(Spinner spinner, String tableName, int addNewTitle) {
        super();

        _mSpinner = spinner;
        _mTableName = tableName;
        _mAdapterUri = BeerBookUriHandler.getUri(tableName);
        _mAddNewTitle = addNewTitle;

        _mAddOptionsCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{Table.COL_ID, BeerTable.COL_NAME});
        _mAddOptionsCursor.addRow(new String[]{"" + ADD_NEW_ID, getString(addNewTitle) + '\u2026'});

        _mSpinner.setOnTouchListener(this);
        _mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    public void setAdapterUri(Uri uri) {
        _mAdapterUri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        _mWasTouched = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (_mWasTouched) {
            // event fired by user
            if (id == ADD_NEW_ID) {
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(AddNewDialogFragment.TITLE, _mAddNewTitle);

                _mAddNewDialogFragment = new AddNewDialogFragment();
                _mAddNewDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
                _mAddNewDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), _mTableName + "AddNewDialog");
            }
        } else {
            // event fired at activity start
            int selection = 0;
            if (_mAdapter.getCount() > 1) {
                selection = 1;
                Uri uri = BeerBookUriHandler.getUri(KegTable.NAME + "/last");
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                        _mTableName + "." + Table.COL_ID
                }, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    long lastUsedId = cursor.getLong(0);
                    selection = getPositionForId(lastUsedId);
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            _mSpinner.setSelection(selection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public void populate() {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_mAdapterUri,
                BEER_PROJECTION, null, null, BeerTable.COL_NAME);
        Cursor extendedCursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{ _mAddOptionsCursor, cursor});

        _mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                SPINNER_LAYOUT, extendedCursor, new String[] { BeerTable.COL_NAME },
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        _mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(SPINNER_ITEM_LAYOUT);
        _mSpinner.setAdapter(_mAdapter);
    }

    public int getPositionForId(long itemId) {
        int pos = 0;
        for(int i = 1, l = _mAdapter.getCount(); i < l; i++)
            if (itemId == _mAdapter.getItemId(i)) {
                pos = i;
                break;
            }

        return pos;
    }

    public long getSelectedId() {
        return _mSpinner.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    public void setSelectionById(long id) {
        _mSpinner.setSelection(getPositionForId(id));
    }
}
```

## KegAddActivity

in `onCreate()` method I instantiate spinners like so

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    final Spinner beerSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.keg_add_beer);
    _mBeerSpinner = new ExtendableSpinner(beerSpinner, BeerTable.NAME, R.string.beer_add);
    // initially disable, wait for brewery selection
    beerSpinner.setEnabled(false);

    final Spinner brewerySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.keg_add_brewery);
    _mBrewerySpinner = new ExtendableSpinner(brewerySpinner, BreweryTable.NAME, R.string.brewery_add) {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            super.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
            if (id > 0) {
                // brewery selected, populate beerSpinner
                Uri uri = BeerBookUriHandler.getUri(BreweryTable.NAME + "/" +
                        getSelectedId() + "/" + BeerTable.NAME);
                _mBeerSpinner.setAdapterUri(uri);
                _mBeerSpinner.populate();
                beerSpinner.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };
    _mBrewerySpinner.populate();

    ...
}
```

## My current suspicion

Because the first spinner works and the second don't and the're pretty similar, I think the spinners concurrent for focus somehow, but I really don't know.
I've tried replace `DialogFragment` with separated Activities dedicated to each spinner and `onItemSelected` event of spinners then called `startActivityForResult()` but this caused the same problem, the first spinner worked good and the second failed with the warning, so the problem might be in code of Spinners.

## Finally some progress!

By luck, I found constellation where it works and then was able to find out why it doesn't.

If the item for *Add new...* is currently selected in the spinner, then selecting *Add new...* item again produce `ignoring focus gain` warning. But if you select some other item in the spinner and then select *Add new...*, it works. The problem was, if there are no other items in the spinner, you cannot perform such reselection. It seems like the `onItemSelected` event is not propagated, if you select an already selected option. But this is major problem, because user can hit *Cancel* at `AddNewDialog` to return back to the main view, and then the *Add new...* will stay selected and could be the only option, so there is no way to open `AddNewDialog` again.

The solution, how to make it work, is to add another, default item, like *Choose from the list...* item and if the user cancels dialog, reselect spinner to default option. I'll test it and keep this post updated.

## Conclusion

If you choose from the `Spinner` an item, which was previously selected, the `itemSelected` event is not propagated and `W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain` warning appears in your log.

Since `Spinner` does not support `onItemClick` event, the only workaround I found working is to define one default option *Choose from the list...* and if the user cancels `AddNewDialog` the `onDialogNegativeClick` listener resets spinner to default *Choose from...* item, so after clickin on *Add new...* there occurs change in selection and the event is propagated.

Comment: By the way you don't need `super()`. You're not extending anything explicitly that requires that.

Comment: Thanks, I've cleared that. It was uncleaned mess from previous hocus- pocus.

Comment: Completely understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We encountered the same problem and determined that the only way around this was to create a custom Spinner that calls `onItemSelected()` even if the same item was selected:

```
public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {

        public CustomSpinner(Context contextArg){
            super(contextArg);
        }

        public CustomSpinner(Context contextArg, AttributeSet attributeSetArg){
            super(contextArg, attributeSetArg);
        }

        public CustomSpinner(Context contextArg, AttributeSet attributeSetArg, int styleArg){
            super(contextArg, attributeSetArg, styleArg);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelection(int positionArg){
            boolean samePosition = positionArg == getSelectedItemPosition();
            super.setSelection(positionArg, false);
            // here we modifiy the Spinner's default behavior
            if(samePosition){
                // we dispatch the event, even if the position is the same
                OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = getOnItemSelectedListener();
                if(onItemSelectedListener != null){
                    onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(this,
                            getSelectedView(),
                            positionArg,
                            getSelectedItemId());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelection(int positionArg, boolean animateArg){
            boolean samePosition = positionArg == getSelectedItemPosition();
            super.setSelection(positionArg, animateArg);
            // here we modifiy the Spinner's default behavior
            if(samePosition){
                // we dispatch the event, even if the position is the same
                OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener = getOnItemSelectedListener();
                if(onItemSelectedListener != null){
                    onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(this,
                            getSelectedView(),
                            positionArg,
                            getSelectedItemId());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Exquisite. Custom spinners just must be in XML styled as `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"` to preserve AppCompat Spinner look.

Comment: @navotera what is that supposed to mean? Please fix your comment or delete it.

Comment: sorry image not uploaded